# How to select specific row from SQL table and join multiple tables in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, sql-server-2014

I am using Northwind database to learn SQL server. I am trying to  run SQL query such that  I can select specific employee (EmployeeID=1) from Employees table, and each order associated with the employee from Orders table, how it was shipped (ship via), the company who shipped it, the total number of days elapsed from order date to shipped date. For that I have below query, I am not sure if my query is correct. Can any one please verify ?

I have tried to run below query

```
  SELECT Employees.EmployeeID,
    Orders.OrderID,DATEDIFF(DAY,Orders.OrderDate,Orders.ShippedDate) AS 'Date 
    Diff',
    Orders.ShipVia,Shippers.ShipperID,Shippers.CompanyName FROM  Employees
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipVia=Shippers.ShipperID
    WHERE Employees.EmployeeID =1
    GROUP BY 

 Orders.ShipVia,Shippers.ShipperID,Shippers.CompanyName,Employees.EmployeeID,Orders.OrderID,Orders.OrderDate,Orders.ShippedDate
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` seems superfluous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. What would be another approach ? Just remove Group BY... I was thinking if there is another way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: you have not used any aggregate function then why are you using group by ..without aggregate it will change the results

Comment: @KedarLimaye.. Would it be possible for you to elaborate ?

Comment: is there a specific requirement from which you have prepare your query?

Comment: @KedarLimaye.. Not really. I am practicing for learning purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few rules to use GROUP BY clause-

1)A SELECT statement clause that divides the query result into groups of rows, usually for the purpose of performing one or more aggregations on each group. The SELECT statement returns one row per group.

2)Specifies a column or a non-aggregate calculation on a column. This column can belong to a table, derived table, or view. The column must appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement, but is not required to appear in the SELECT list.

3)The column must appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement, but is not required to appear in the SELECT list. However, each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the  list must be included in the GROUP BY list

These are some important points from Documentation related to SQL Server

Hopes this solve your problem or clear your concept.

More information at-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for explanation and link